# Clustering\Grouping Challenge - clustering pairs into groups

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a clustering challenge ...

I have many pairs of data (e.g. A<-->B, C<-->D, E<-->F, A<-->F and so on)
I need to group\cluster them into N groups, e.g. Group#1: A,B,F Group #2: C,D.
The clustering shall be done using the given pairs association (i.e. A and B are paired)

Any idea? I'm rather sure there are algorithms for that, but not sure how to look for them.